# Run server side and front side at the same time

Tags: node.js, reactjs

How to run client and server code at the same time? I have a folder `back-end-server` (Node.js) and another folder `front-end-react` (React.js). In my package.json I tried to write:

```
"scripts": {
    "server-dev": "nodemon --prefix back-end-server server.js",
    "client-dev": "npm start --prefix front-end-react",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server-dev\" \"npm run client-dev\""
}
```

`server.js` is a file in the folder `back-end-server` that I want to run at the same time with React folder: `front-end-react`, but they don't run at the same time when I call `npm run dev`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an NPM Package:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently

Then you use scripts on package.json one for the client, and one for the server, and using concurrently run both at the same time (on different ports)

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node backend/server",
    "server": "nodemon backend/server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
}
```

In this case, the backend and front are different folders for the Node and React projects.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have them running in different shells on different ports. The other solution could be simply build front-end files and depoy as static files on a web server like Apache and Nginx which are configured to contact backend.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you are trying to run both the apps but due to port clash they are not starting.

if that's the case you can change the port, something like this:

```
npm start --port 3002
```